# Summing selected elements of a matrix in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, indices

I have a [n x n] matrix containing values belonging to different groups, and a [1 x n] vector defining to which group each element belongs.
(n usually ~1E4, in this example n=4)

I want to calculate a matrix obtained by summing together all the elements belonging to the same group.

I use np.where() to calculate the indices where the elements of each group are located.
When I use the calculated indices, I do not obtain the expected elements, because I select pairs of positions instead of ranges (I'm used to Matlab, where I can simply select M(idx1,idx2) ).

```py
import numpy as np

n=4
M = np.random.rand(n,n)
print(M)

# This vector defines to which group each element belong
belongToGroup = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2])

nGroups=np.max(belongToGroup);

# Calculate a matrix obtained by summing elements belonging to the same group
M_sum = np.zeros((nGroups+1,nGroups+1))
for g1 in range(nGroups+1):
    idxG1 = np.where(belongToGroup==g1)
    for g2 in range(nGroups+1):
        idxG2 = np.where(belongToGroup==g2)
        print('g1 = ' + str(g1))
        print('g2 = ' + str(g2))
        print(idxG1[0])
        print(idxG2[0])
        print(M[idxG1[0],idxG2[0]])
        print(np.sum(M[idxG1[0],idxG2[0]]))
        M_sum[g1,g2]=np.sum(M[idxG1[0],idxG2[0]])

print('')
print('Example of the problem:')
print('Elements I would like to sum to obtain M_sum[0,0]')
print(M[0:2,0:2])
print('Elements that are summed instead')
print(M[[0,1],[0,1]])
```

Example of the problem:
In the example above, the element M_sum[0,0] should be the sum of M[0,0], M[0,1], M[1,0], and M[1,1]
Instead, it is calculated as the sum of M[0,0] and M[1,1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MATLAB, indexing with 2 lists (actually matrices) picks a block.  `numpy` on the other hand tries to broadcast the indexing arrays against each other, and returns selected points.  Its behavior is close to what `sub2ind` does in MATLAB.

```
In [971]: arr = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)                                      
In [972]: arr                                                                   
Out[972]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
In [973]: i1, i2 = np.array([0,2,3]), np.array([1,2,0])
```

Indexing with 2 1d arrays of the same size:

```
In [974]: arr[i1,i2]
Out[974]: array([ 1, 10, 12])
```

This, in effect returns `[arr[0,1], arr[2,2], arr[3,0]]`, one element for each point of matching indices.

But if I turn one index into a 'column vector', it selects from rows, while `i2` selects from columns.

```
In [975]: arr[i1[:,None], i2]                                                   
Out[975]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  0],
       [ 9, 10,  8],
       [13, 14, 12]])
```

MATLAB makes the block indexing easy, while individual access is harder. In `numpy` the block access is a bit harder, though the underlying mechanics is the same.

With your example `i1[0]` and `i2[0]` can be arrays like:

```
array([0, 2]), array([3])
(2,) (1,)
```

The shape (1,) array can broadcast with the (2,) or with a (2,1) array just as well.  Your code would fail if instead `is[0]` were `np.array([0,1,2])`, a (3,) array which can't pair with the (2,) array.  But with a (2,1) it produces a (2,3) block.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried changing the following line:
M_sum[g1,g2]=np.sum(M[idxG1[0],idxG2[0]])  
Into the following: 
M_sum[g1,g2]=np.sum(M[idxG1[:,None],idxG2[0]]) 
Maybe I misunderstood. I get an error "tuple indices must be integers, not tuple"

Comment: You still need to use the `[0]`.  `idxG1` produced by `where` is a `tuple`, one element per dimension of the source.  `idxG1[0]` gives you the indexing array for the 1st dimension.  `idxG1[0][:,None]` adds a dimension to that.  That ":,None" expression is actually a `tuple`.  In Python, almost every expression containing a comma is a tuple :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.ix_` to obtain matlab-ish behavior:

```
A = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
A[[1,2],[0,2]]
# array([3, 8])
A[np.ix_([1,2],[0,2])]
# array([[3, 5],
#        [6, 8]])
```

Under the hood, `np.ix_` does what @hpaulj describes in detail:

```
np.ix_([1,2],[0,2])
# (array([[1],
#        [2]]), array([[0, 2]]))
```

You can apply this to your specific problem as follows:

```
M = np.random.randint(0, 10, (n, n))
M
# array([[6, 2, 7, 1],
#        [6, 7, 9, 5],
#        [9, 4, 3, 2],
#        [3, 1, 7, 9]])
idx = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2])

ng = idx.max() + 1
out = np.zeros((ng, ng), M.dtype)
np.add.at(out, np.ix_(idx, idx), M)
out
# array([[25,  6,  3],
#        [15,  7,  5],
#        [10,  1,  9]])
```

As an aside: There is a faster but less obvious solution that relies on flat indexing:

```
np.bincount(np.ravel_multi_index(np.ix_(idx, idx), (ng, ng)).ravel(), M.ravel(), ng*ng).reshape(ng, ng)
# array([[25.,  6.,  3.],
#        [15.,  7.,  5.],
#        [10.,  1.,  9.]])
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked too. 

To summarize:
WRONG:  
    M_sum[g1,g2]=np.sum(M[idxG1[0],idxG2[0]]) 
CORRECT 1 (thank you @hpaulj )  
    M_sum[g1,g2]=np.sum(M[idxG1[0][:,None],idxG2[0]])  
CORRECT 2 (thank you Paul Panzer )  
    M_sum[g1,g2]=np.sum(M[np.ix_(idxG1[0],idxG2[0])])